# Is it possible print into one line per process in python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I haven't found a good solution for the following problem so far:

```
def do_work() -> None:
    print("Start work", end="")

    # some long running operation

    print("done")

def main():
    with Pool(workers) as p:
        for i in range(100):
            p.apply_async(func=do_work)
    
        p.close()
        p.join()
```

The output I would like to have is

```
Start work...done
Start work...done
Start work...done
...
Start work...done
```

Of course this is not the case, since every process outputs at different times. Question is, can this be achieved without additional dependencies?

Comment: As the "done" should be printed later in a line which may not be the last one, it would need special codes sent to the terminal to move the cursor to the desired location. This may be complicated and OS dependent. Without additional dependencies it would require to copy parts of an appropriate library into your code or to write this from scratch.

Comment: This question isn't about Python; it's about how the terminal works and about how standard output streams work.

Comment: You might want to take a look to the built in library [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html).

Comment: So in short: this is not achievable without additional libraries or complex code additions. I have decided to print the `done` in separate lines. harder to read for the user, but my application is just a simple uploading tool for a s3 storage so not worth the work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only "dependencies" are classes that are part of the standard Python library. Does that work for you?

The "trick" is to have your output written to a string and then finally print that string. To accomplish this you need to use an `io.StringIO` instance as your string buffer and *temporarily* replace `sys.stdout` with this buffer:

```py
def do_work() -> None:
    from contextlib import redirect_stdout
    from io import StringIO

    buffer = StringIO()
    with redirect_stdout(buffer):
        print("Start work", end="...")

        # some long running operation

        print("done")
    print(buffer.getvalue(), end='', flush=True)

def main():
    from multiprocessing import Pool

    with Pool(4) as p:
        for i in range(4): # Reduced range for demo purposes
            p.apply_async(func=do_work)

        p.close()
        p.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```None
Start work...done
Start work...done
Start work...done
Start work...done
```

Or you can create a decorator to do this:

```py
def buffer_output(f):
    from functools import wraps
    
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        from contextlib import redirect_stdout
        from io import StringIO

        buffer = StringIO()
        with redirect_stdout(buffer):
            return_value = f(*args, **kwargs)
        print(buffer.getvalue(), end='', flush=True)
        return return_value
    return wrapper

@buffer_output
def do_work() -> None:
    print("Start work", end="...")

    # some long running operation

    print("done")

def main():
    from multiprocessing import Pool

    with Pool(4) as p:
        for i in range(4): # Reduced range for demo purposes
            p.apply_async(func=do_work)

        p.close()
        p.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If the issue is that you cannot modify the worker function `do_work` at all, then create a new worker function:

```py
def buffer_output(f):
    from functools import wraps

    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        from contextlib import redirect_stdout
        from io import StringIO

        buffer = StringIO()
        with redirect_stdout(buffer):
            return_value = f(*args, **kwargs)
        print(buffer.getvalue(), end='', flush=True)
        return return_value
    return wrapper

def do_work() -> None:
    print("Start work", end="...")

    # some long running operation

    print("done")


@buffer_output
def worker():
    return do_work()

def main():
    from multiprocessing import Pool

    with Pool(4) as p:
        for i in range(4): # Reduced range for demo purposes
            # Call our new worker:
            p.apply_async(func=worker)

        p.close()
        p.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```